# .htaccess убрать из урл ?_utl_t= и оставить только то, что до него

Tags: .htaccess, apache, seo

В Яндексе куча дублей страниц такого вида

```
/product1.php?_utl_t=vk
/product2.php?_utl_t=ok
/blabla.php?_utl_t=tw
```

Это переходы со ссылок на страницы из соцсетей. Ссылки заводились туда, очевидно,такой штукой, как uptolike...
Как преобразовать урлы в такие с помощью .htaccess? Рубить все, что угодно после знака вопроса не вариант, можно поломать что-то нужное! )

```
/product1.php
/product2.php
/blabla.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Городить надо что-то такое, чтоб убрать один параметр из query string, расположенный в произвольном месте

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)&*_utl_t=[^&]+(&*.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

[Тут](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/?share=88bd4435-b33e-5d32-8d56-f2bfcac48403) работает, но он соврет, недорого возьмет. проверяйте на живом

Comment: Из /product1.php?_utl_t=vk преобразовало в /product1.php?k

Comment: нынешнюю версию возьмите, я там подправлял - жадность поуменьшал :)

Comment: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=691dec81-65a8-5e86-a8b3-2c396748d683

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло!